# Curiosities in deserializing collections with gson 2

Tags: collections, gson

I have these classes

```
public class Application {
    public String name;
    public String ico;
    public List<MenuStruct> menu =new ArrayList<MenuStruct>();
    //Constructor
    public Application() {  }
}
public class MenuStruct {
    public String id;
    public String type;    
    public String parent;  
    public String name;    
    public String secId;   
    //Constructor   
    public MenuStruct() {}
}
```

If I try to deserialize a collection directly in this way:

```
ApplicationManager apm= new ApplicationManager();
s="[  {\"name\":\"reg_salida\" , \"ico\":\"document-open-2-32x32.ico\"    }]";
apm.apps=(new Gson()).fromJson(s,apm.apps.getClass() );
for (Application ap:apm.apps){
    System.out.println(ap.name); //gets error here
}
```

I get a java.lang.ClassCastException.

But if I try to deserialize its containig class ApplicationManager it does not fail.

```
s="{ \"apps\": [ {\"name\":\"reg_salida\" , \"ico\":\"document-open-2-32x32.ico\" }]}";
ApplicationManager apm=(new Gson()).fromJson(s,ApplicationManager.class);
for (Application ap:apm.apps){
    System.out.println(ap.name); // now no errors here! and shows reg_salida
}
```

Is this a bug of gson 2.2.4? or maybe I am doing something not correct?

Eduard.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to provide full definition of property class. Your example should looks like that:

```
manager.apps = gson.fromJson(json, new TypeToken<List<Application>>() {}.getType());
```

Comment: I'm glad I could help you. Could you check my answer as a helpful and up-vote.